# How to retrieve individual values in the list?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I'm new to Janusgraph database. I have created a property key with cardinality as "LIST" and added that property to a vertex. Now I would like to retrieve individual value of that vertex's property. Currently I'm getting entire list as a string.

```
youtubeUrls = graph.makePropertyKey('youturls').dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.LIST).make()
```

```
urls = graph.addVertex(T.label, 'urls', 'youturls', ["google.com", "yahoo.com", "geekbull.in"])
```

I am not able to get the first value from the list. I tried so many ways like below,

```
g.V(urls).values('youturls')[0]
```

But I'm getting entire list as one string. Where am I doing mistake? Any suggestions and solutions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The way you add the values is wrong, you need to add each String separately.

```
g.addV('url').
    property(list, 'youturls', 'google.com').
    property(list, 'youturls', 'yahoo.com').
    property(list, 'youturls', 'geekbull.in').iterate()
```

Then, when it comes to querying, you can access a specific value like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().map(values('youturls').range(0,1))
==>google.com
gremlin> g.V().map(values('youturls').range(1,2))
==>yahoo.com
gremlin> g.V().map(values('youturls').range(2,3))
==>geekbull.in
```